# Oracle DBD Error from Perl script

Tags: sql, oracle, perl

I am trying to run perl script but i get an oracle error.

```
DBD::Oracle::db prepare failed: ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated (DBD ERROR: OCIStmtPrepare)
```

But this SQL QUERY perfectly works fine in TOAD

MY perl connection details:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass, { RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 0 });
    my $sth=$dbh->prepare($SQL);
    $sth->execute or die "EXEC ERROR $sth->errstr";
```

sql query:

```
SELECT name FROM employee WHERE
            event IN ('IPO', 'RIGHTS')
        AND (NOT market_code = 'ID' OR NOT event = 'RIGHTS')
        AND NOT market_code = 'IN'
        AND NOT market_code = 'NZ'
        AND name NOT LIKE '%stat%'
          AND NOT REGEXP_LIKE (name, 'S.K(Q|S)$')
          AND name NOT LIKE '.%'
          AND name NOT LIKE '%ol.SI'
          AND name NOT LIKE '%bi.SI'
```

Comment: Could you show the Perl code which creates `$SQL` please?  Also try printing `$SQL` to check it's what you think it is.  BTW  the `or die` is unnecessary since you have RaiseError on.

Comment: Is the sql query the content of `$SQL`?

Comment: You have a `$` in there. Maybe that confused Perl when creating the query text?

Comment: yes u got it  :) i removed the $ line it works now.

Comment: how i need to modify my perl connections to accept $ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl will interpolate double-quoted string literals, like

```
 my $SQL = "REGEXP_LIKE (name, 'S.K(Q|S)$')";
```

In here, your "variable" `$'` will be replaced with its value.

If you don't want that, use a non-interpolating version:

```
 my $SQL = q{REGEXP_LIKE (name, 'S.K(Q|S)$')};
```

Single-quoted strings would also do, but since you have single quotes inside, the `q{}` is convenient. You can choose any terminator you want (such as `q[]`) and you can make it interpolate, too, with `qq{}`.

Comment: hi Thilo . thank you very much !!!!!it perfectly works tried my $SQL = q{REGEXP_LIKE (name, 'S.K(Q|S)$')};